# Get touch coordinates in TextView when using scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, textview, ontouchlistener

I need to calculate the touch location on a TextView and calculate it's character offset.
I'm using

```
int line = layout.getLineForVertical(event.getY());
int characterOffset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line , event.getX());
```

in a TextView  `OnTouchListener` to get the touch coordinates and convert it to a character offset in the current `TextView`. It works perfectly and give the place of the character which is clicked.
But when I'm using method: `textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` to active scrolling for the `TextView` , the former operations to calculate the touch location would not work anymore because it can't calculate the scrolled lines and consider the touch coordinated from the beginning of the TextView.
How can I fix this and is there any way for getting scrolled value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
View.getScrollX() and/or View.getScrollY()
```